# send data through multiple usb GPRS devices

Tags: .net, gprs

i would like to send a HD video through multiple USB GPRS devices ( offered by companies like vodafone, orange etc. ) to a server .

How can i identify each GPRS device and send through it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sockets you can bind a socket to a given interface with [`Socket.Bind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) before you use `Socket.Connect`.

You can use [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx) to find all network interfaces, their types and the IP to use with `Socket.Bind()`.

**Edit**
I assume there are services and/or applications closer to the network layer that can combine several physical interfaces to a logical interface with automatic load balancing. I have not worked with any such solutions and can not recommend any specific.

Comment: can i send more data on a particular GPRS device ? ( maybe one has a larger broadband than others )

Comment: @Badescu, The `NetworkInterface` class gives you a link speed, but that gives you the highest possible speed the device can handle, not the actual transfer rate. I don't know of any good pattern to determine actual throughput, I would try to set the buffer size to be fairly small to detect when one connection fills up and use the other.